# jQuery code conflicts

Tags: jquery, conflict

Apologies for the generic title.

I have two jQuery files, one handles form submissions and one handles page hyperlinks.

The form submission checks that the form entries are not blank, if it is - it informs the user and will display an error message, when the form is filled in the form data is passed to a processing file.

The hyperlinks loads new page data into a div, this new page data often includes forms as handled by the processing file.

I don't know why - but ~60% of the time the form submission will 'refresh' on click and load the main index page OR the page last visited. This seems entirely random.

I can't see why this is happening and if anyone can show me I would greatly appreciate it.

Form submission code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.ajax_form').submit(function() {

        // check for empty inputs
        var errors = 0;
        $(".ajax_form :input").map(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()) {
                errors++;
            }  
        });

        // if empty inputs inform user
        if(errors > 0){
            $('#results').text("All fields are required");
            return false;
        }

        // hide form and show loader
        $(".ajax_form").slideUp("normal");
        $('#results').html('<span id="load">Loading..</span>');

        // post data to processing file
        $.post(
            'processing.php',
            $(this).serialize(),
            function(data){
                $("#results").slideDown("normal");
                $("#results").html(data)
            }
        );

        return false;

    });

});
```

Navigation code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // if hash is already set, load linked data
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    $('#nav li a').each(function(){
        if(hash == $(this).attr('href')){
            var toLoad = hash + '.php';
            $('#content').load(toLoad)
        }
    });

    // each menu item on click load linked data
    $('#nav li a').click(function(){

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + '.php';
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#content').prepend('<span id="load">Loading..</span>');
        $('#content').hide();
        $('#content').load(toLoad);
        $('#content').slideDown('normal');

        return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: My rough guess is that that click function fails for some reason and does not return false, causing the link to open like normal. Do you get any errors in JavaScript console?

Comment: Maybe you should check `if(!$(this).val().length) { errors++; }`? Also, your `return false;` is way down the code. You should use `$('.ajax_form').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... });`

Comment: are you loading jquery from a cdn?

Comment: I get no errors no, the form does appear to submit 'normally' though. As mentioned below I tried preventDefault(); - same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your form refreshes because before reaching the part of `return false;`, the **scripts breaks**
 somewhere before.

Use `firebug` or similar to detect this. Be sure to handle all outcomes or every condition.

May be a quick dry run can detect the gaps.